# AS3 Flex Embed Image to Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

What is the difference between:

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/graphic.png")]
const GRAPHIC:Class;
var graphic:Bitmap = new GRAPHIC();
addChild(graphic);
```

And:

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/graphic.png")]
const GRAPHIC:Class;
addChild(new GRAPHIC());
```

And which one of these should I use and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a variable pointer to the instantiated copy of the `GRAPHIC` class.  The second is an implicit declaration.

You would use the pointer if you needed to perform further operations on the object.  For example...

```
graphic.name = "myGraphic";
graphic.alpha = 0.5;
someFunction(graphic);
```

Setting properties, and passing it as an argument to other functions are good cases for a pointer.  If you don't need to do this, you can use the implicit declaration.  You can do this in other places when it makes sense.  For example...

```
var settings:Object = {
    "x":20,
    "alpha":0.5
}
setProperties(foo, settings);

// Instead, you can do it in one line, with an implicit declaration.
setProperties(foo, {"x":20, "alpha":0.5});
```